# subdomain redirection to domain , and keep url paths in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I got a subdomain http://wwww.sub.domain.com

I want all links from this subdomain be redirected to a target domain with www, nonwww and also redirect the path.

REDIRECT:

www = http://www.sub.domain.com

path = http://sub.domain.com/something/anything

to TARGET:

http://www.domain.com/something/anything

I used :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

its not wokring as excepted , what did i missed here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```

Please note that you're redirecting to `https` in the code, but stating that redirect should be to `http` in your question.